# Android: What happens when you change the dimensions of a frameLayout that is set to wrap_content programmatically?

Tags: java, android, android-xml

I have a FrameLayout in my application and in the xml file its `width` and `height` is set to `wrap_content` . then I want to change its dimensions programmatically like this :

```
FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
ViewGroup.LayoutParams previewParam = preview.getLayoutParams() ;
previewParam.height =(int) (height * 0.86);
previewParam.width = (int)(previewParam.height/ratio) ;
preview.setLayoutParams(previewParam) ;
```

When I do this the program exits when I start this activity, is the problem with `wrap_content` or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe its because `previewParam`  is null at that point. Try doing it like this:

```
FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.abs__action_bar);
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams((height/ratio),
         (int) (height * 0.86));
preview.setLayoutParams(params);
preview.requestLayout();
```